# Visual Studio crashes when renaming ADO.NET Source component

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have created a new Integration Services Project in Visual Studio 2015. I have added a package with a Data Flow Task. In this task I have added the ADO.NET Source component with a simple SQL query as the command. In the Expressions editor of the Data Flow Task I have added an expression for the [ADO NET Source].[SqlCommand] property with (currently) the same SQL query. This SSIS package runs successfully.

Now, when I rename the ADO.NET Source component in the Data Flow Task and want to save the package, Visual Studio crashes. The following information is logged in the Event Log:

**1st Event**

Source: .Net Runtime

Message:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSPackagePersist100.SavePackageToXML(System.Object ByRef, Boolean, Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSEvents100)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package.SaveToXML(System.String ByRef, Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.IDTSEvents)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.Serialization.DtrDesignerSerializer.SerializePackage(System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager, Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package, System.IO.TextWriter)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.Serialization.DtrDesignerSerializer.SerializeComponent(System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager, System.ComponentModel.IComponent, System.Object)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Serialization.DesignerComponentSerializer.Serialize(System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager, System.Object)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Designer.Serialization.DataWarehouseDesignerLoader.Serialize()
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Designer.Serialization.BaseDesignerLoader.Flush(Boolean)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Designer.Serialization.BaseDesignerLoader.Flush()
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Designer.Serialization.DataWarehouseContainerManager.OnBeforeSave(UInt32)
```

**2nd Event**

Source: Application Error

Message:

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.25420.1, time stamp: 0x57685d85
Faulting module name: DTS.dll, version: 2017.140.800.90, time stamp: 0x5964da54
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00070c07
Faulting process id: 0x1660
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3c4ee248a88f4
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\DTS.dll
Report Id: 9b9d1a33-4974-480f-a6b0-91bf7658045f
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

[[image: Video thumbnail]

Check this video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNfsadTOzhg)

Does anybody have an idea on solving this problem?

Thanks,
Danny

Comment: I've has some SSIS oddities with tasks misbehaving. My "Go to" solution is to delete the task and re create it. I've often found that Excel sources can cause similar problems when the column layouts change. I can resolve this issue by deleting the Excel task and then re add it! If this fails then try removing / reapplying the connection manager!

Comment: Thanks @MiguelH!
I also found a workaround, where I first remove the [ADO NET Source].[SqlCommand] Expression and then rename the Data Flow component. 

But, I hope someone has a better and constructive solution!